# Using Spring Util Schema to Override Bean Settings In App Context

Tags: java, spring

First: yes, I've seen the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html).

They tell me how to create a util:list, util:set, etc. I get that part.

However, I have a library with an application context that contains a bean (specifically a Hibernate Session Factory bean) with settings I'd like the option of overriding. Several services use this library, not every service needs the same annotated classes.

The session factory bean currently looks something like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" >

        <list>
            <value>com.example.model.Person</value>
            <value>com.example.model.Section</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to replace the annotatedClasses property with a list defined like this (in the app context of the service using the library):

```
<util:list id="serviceSpecificAnnotatedClasses">
    <value>com.example.model.Person</value>
    <value>com.example.model.Section</value>
    <value>com.example.model.Location</value>
</util:list>
```

Do I simply have to name the util:list "annotatedClasses" and it will be automatically overriden?

Answer (score 1):

No it wont automatically be overriden. You would have to declare the bean and wire it by default.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" ref="annotatedClasses" />
</bean>

<util:list id="annotatedClasses">
    <value>com.example.model.Person</value>
    <value>com.example.model.Section</value>
    <value>com.example.model.Location</value>
</util:list>
```

No others can simply override the list `annotatedClasses`.

But why not simply use a property-placeholder to specify the classes and add a comma delimited list to a properties file?

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" value="${service.annotatedClasses}" />
</bean>
```

Assuming that each service has its own property file for configuration they simply need to add the value for **service.annotatedClasses**.

Comment: To Clarify: the util:list could NOT be declared in the service's app context, but instead the service would have to declare it's own session factory bean with the list of values I want?

Comment: Must be me but I don't get this comment, why would the service need to declare the sessionfactory again?

Comment: The library being referenced is large, but each service only makes use of some of the entities defined in the library. The idea was to put a <util:list> in each service to override (or even set) the "annotatedClasses" property of the session factory defined in the library application context's SessionFactory bean.

Comment: Which is what I explained in the first code snippet... Simply define 2 beans, that way services can simply override the list by adding a bean with the same name to their own context.